# Segmentation fault on bash script

Tags: linux, bash

i have a bash script that shows "Segment Violation" on line

```
sp-sc-auth "${sopUrl}" 8809 8908 > /dev/null &
```

but when `sp-sc-auth` is executed from terminal works fine

I set:

```
set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
set -o xtrace
set -o nounset
```

end script continue executing but throws that "Segment Violation" error...

System is a debian 64 bits

Thanks in advance
Regars

The ugly code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Init
set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
#set -o xtrace
set -o nounset

__DIR__="$(cd "$(dirname "${0}")"; echo $(pwd))"
__BASE__="$(basename "${0}")"
__FILE__="${__DIR__}/${__BASE__}"

ARG1="${1:-Undefined}"

display_usage() {
    scriptName=$(basename $0)   
    echo -e "Uso:\n "${scriptName}" [6,7,8,9,10 o 12]"
    echo "Sin especificar el canal, búsqueda de retransmisiones"
}

parse_arenavision() {
url="http://www.arenavision.in/agenda"

if ! av=$(curl -s "${url}");then
    echo "Sin conexión"
    exit 1
fi
started="off"
declare -a _list
element=""

while read line
do
if [[ $line =~ (([0-9][0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+.*)) ]]; then
    element=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" | sed -r 's#CET|AV([^6789]|1[02])##g; s#<br />##g; s#//|&.*;##g; s#/\s*$##g; s#INGLATERRA/PREMIER LEAGUE#PREMIER#g; s#ITALIA/SERIE A#SERIE A#g; s#ITALIA/SERIE A#SERIE A#g;' | tr -dc '[:print:]')
    if [[ "${element}" =~ (.*AV[6789]|.*AV10|.*AV12) ]]; then
    _list+=("${element}")
    fi
    started="on"
else
    if [[ ${started} == "on" ]]; then
        break
    fi
fi
done <<< "${av}"

for i in "${_list[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ (.*BALONCESTO.*) ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[92m${i}\e[0m"
    elif [[ "${i}" =~ (.*LIGA BBVA.*) ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[37m${i}\e[0m"
    else 
        echo "${i}"
    fi
done

}

case $ARG1 in
    "Undefined" )
        parse_arenavision
        exit 0
        ;;
    [6789] )
        page="${ARG1}"
        ;;
    10 )
        page="${ARG1}"
        ;;
    * )
        display_usage
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

# Delete "zombies"
if pgrep -f "sp-sc"
then
    kill -9 `pgrep -f "sp-sc-auth"`
fi

url="http://www.arenavision.in/arenavision$page"

# Get url content and url sop
if ! content=$(curl -s "${url}");then
    echo "Sin conexión"
fi

if [[ $content =~ (sop://([A-Za-z0-9_]+|\.)+:[0-9]+) ]]; then
    sopUrl=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "No se ha encontrado la url"
    exit 1
fi

# Connect ArenaVision 1
children=""
trap 'kill $children 1>/dev/null 2>&1; exit 143' EXIT

sp-sc-auth "${sopUrl}" 8809 8908 > /dev/null &
children="$!"

# Check if exists
line='[                ]'
for i in {0..15}
do
replace="${line/ /#}"
line=$replace
echo -ne "Comprobando sopcast  ${replace}" \\r
sleep 1
done
echo -ne "\033[2K"

if ! kill -0 "${children}" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Sin emisión"
    exit 1
else
    echo -ne "Comprobando sopcast  [ OK ]" \\r
    echo
fi

# Open VLC player
line='[                          ]'
for i in {0..25}
do
replace="${line/ /#}"
line=$replace
echo -ne "Cargando reproductor ${replace}" \\r
sleep 1
done
if ! kill -0 "${children}" 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Fallo en recepción"
    exit 1
else
    vlc http://localhost:8908/tv.asf 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    echo -ne "\033[2K"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Would I be correct to guess that your native language is Python? :)

Comment: Anyhow -- the `kill -0 $children` check should detect when the segfault took place, to let your code error out there as it is.

Comment: One thing I would suggest, by the way, is to get out of the habit of using `echo -e` -- see the POSIX spec for echo, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section; `echo -e` is incompatible with both pure POSIX and XSI-extended POSIX. `printf` is by far the more portable tool.

Comment: ...but for the segfault, the place to start there is by collecting a core file and reading it using gdb (with debug symbols installed) to grok just where and how the failure is taking place. Just out of curiosity, by the way -- does redirecting stdin (`</dev/null`) have any effect, either in the script or on the command-line invocation? It's a bit of a long shot, but not utterly implausible.

Comment: lol! weird code, i know... Buff i dont get it! i don't understand....redirect stdin using </dev/null?

Comment: Using `</dev/null` makes the program's stdin point to a perpetually empty device (`/dev/null`), rather than a pointer to the TTY that's active when you run the script. Sometimes that makes a difference -- if your program tries to poll for input when it sees that its stdin is a tty, for instance; that's not unheard of (mplayer and similar tools do such tricks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errexit` **cannot** work on programs run in the background, so this is unsurprising -- the inline command is simply starting a background process, and that (starting a background process) succeeds, even if the process itself subsequently fails.

If you call `wait $!` subsequently, *then* `errexit` will be able to take effect, as the `wait` call will exit with the exit status of the program itself. (Of course, if you *can* call `wait $!`, then this raises the question of why you were backgrounding the initial program to start with).

---

If you always want to kill the parent script if the child fails, you can do this instead:

```
(sp-sc-auth "$sopUrl" 8809 8908 >/dev/null || kill $$) &
```

`$$` evaluates to the PID of the parent shell, not the subshell, so this will act accordingly.

---

As for the segfault itself, "program X segfaults" is a question too vague to be addressed here. To even start debugging that, you'd need to collect the core dump created on its failure (enabling cores if necessary), install debug symbols for sopcast, and use gdb to collect a stack trace from the core file created on failure.

Comment: Thank you Charles!, i run sp-sc-auth in background because i have no idea about bash and i need that this program run while a time before run vlc to play streaming. I show you my ugly code in edit comment: